# Getting Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' error even when multiDex is enabled

Tags: android, build.gradle, androidx, android-multidex

I'm trying to run the app on my device but am getting this error every time:

> Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Here's `build.gradle (Module: app)`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
        // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
        // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
        // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
        // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    implementation('com.kc.androidunsplash:androidunsplash:1.0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

I've searched a lot for the solution but haven't found any yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see that you are migrating to android to androidx

[Here is official documentation for the migration from androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

For the above issue you need to change your gradle file like below

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.backpaper.backpapers"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       // multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation('com.kc.androidunsplash:androidunsplash:1.0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'

}
```

Inside activity_main layout file change it to

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
```

Inside MainActivity import

```
   import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```